# How to use Shared preferences in singleton of other class which not include context?

Tags: android

I got a singleton. In methods of this singleton i need to get access to shared preferences. How I can do that?

```
public class SubscriptionManager {
private static SubscriptionManager instance = null;
private SubscriptionManager() {}
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

public static SubscriptionManager getInstance() {
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new SubscriptionManager();
    return instance;
}

public void setFreeOpenSubscription(){
    //here i need to write something like
    // String type = mPrefs.getValue("type");
}
```

}

Comment: Use a dependency inversion framework (Dagger, Koin, etc.), have it manage your singleton, and have it inject a `Context` that you can use.

Comment: @CommonsWare im not allowed to use libraries

Comment: Then you cannot build the app, as everything in Android is built using libraries.

Comment: @CommonsWare not as a rule. One of the solutions here not use a singleton but use regular one. But trying to find the way with singleton

Comment: You can pass context from where you want access the singleton method or  better pass shared preferences value  instead pass context. Create application class and access through Applicationcontext.

Comment: @Thirumalai ahhh so initiate preferences in activity and send it as a parameter in the method. correct?

Comment: @Boris Ruzanov - Yes